# Prove that if $X$ is and infinite set and $Y$ is countable or finite, then $|X \cup Y| = |X|$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $X$ be an infinite set and $Y$ a finite or countable set. Prove that $|X \cup Y| = |X|$.

The form to prove this is by finding a bijection between both sets $X \cup Y$ and $X$. I got a hint to use the property that every infinite set has a finite or countable subset. My problem is how to define this bijection. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ has a countably infinite subset $C$. Note that the union of a countably infinite set with an at most countable set is countably infinite hence $C \cup Y$ is countably infinite. Thus we have a bijection $f:X \to X \cup Y$ given by

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x  & x \in {X}\setminus{C} \\
g(x) & x \in C
\end{cases}$$

where $g$ is some bijection from $C$ to $C \cup Y$.

This uses axiom of choice, however.